# Django using URL parameters to query database in class-based view

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, url-parameters

I have a form which when submitted goes to a results page where the URL would be for example:

```
appname/results/?make=BMW
```

I want to use the URL parameters to query database and display the results on that page.

This is the code I have so far:

views

```
class SearchView(FormView):

    template_name = 'carproject/search.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = AdvancedSearch(self.request.GET or None)
        context = {'form': form}
        if form.is_valid():
            return render(request, 'carproject/results.html')
        else:
            return render(request, self.template_name, context)

class ResultsView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'carproject/results.html'

    def get_queryset(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        make = self.request.GET.get('make')
        results = Vehicles.objects.filter(makename__icontains='make')
        context = {'results': results}

        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

HTML

```
<table>
{% for item in results%}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{item.makename}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.model}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.seriesname}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.seatingcapacity}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.pricenew}}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't konw what the question is,but you should change

```
results = Vehicles.objects.filter(makename__icontains='make')
```

to

```
results = Vehicles.objects.filter(makename__icontains=make)
```

`'make'` -> `make`